# TFLite cross-compiling arm64 build error?

Tags: tensorflow, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite, arm64

As I am currently trying to Tensorflow lite for ARM64 architecture, I just try to follow the instructions from below:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64#cross-compile_for_arm64

But I simply get a compilation error:
tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/ruy/ruy/cpuinfo.cc:9:21: fatal error: cpuinfo.h: No such file or directory

I am surprised this starting build not working out of the box.

Btw, I am trying to do the above in Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

Anybody had the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

Solved now. You need to explicity install Bazel for this.
The tensorflow-lite dependencies script does not do this. Not sure why, should have been part of this.